# Fuel pump on the car not working as the fuel cuts off

Tags: electrical, fuel-pump, tata, indi

I have a Tata Indica 1.4 the car has a new fuel pump inside.

When I drive the car cuts electrical power to the pump; then there is 0 volts. After about 20min, the car starts and runs again for about 5km, then cuts again.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!